Proverb request: A person who is very stubborn
In India, we say, "It was a one legged hen."
"This saying may have originated from an incident where a king's cook ate a chicken leg while preparing biryani. When the king asked about the missing leg, the cook claimed it was a one-legged hen. Despite being caught, the cook stubbornly stuck to his story, leading to the phrase 'one-legged hen' describing someone who stubbornly clings to a false claim."
I am looking for an English equivalent which can be used to describe someone who is being stubborn or sticking to their own false or incorrect statement.

Bald-faced liar
Originally this was "bold" because it means someone who ignores how easily the lie is detected, but semantic drift took over.

I can't think of an English proverb with an equivalent meaning, but there are a few phrases that might be useful
Blind to the truth - the truth is there but you won't accept it.
Stubborn as a mule - mule are said to refuse to move however they are enticed.
Going down with the ship - ship's crew (particularly the captain) stay on a sinking ship despite means of escape being available.
In the face of reality - refusing to accept the evidence.
But none of them completely convey the same meaning.

It sure feels like there should be an idiom for this. But if there were, I'm sure we would have heard it used to refer to Trump at some time.

I don't think there is an English equivalent, but I'll add to Peter's suggestions.
These address holding on to an idea, but they apply whether that idea is true or false:

Stick to your guns

Dig in your heels


These address an idea that's false, but aren't that strong on holding on to the idea:

Bury your head in the sand

Refuse to face facts


